# Was there a contingency plan in place if Little Boy failed to detonate?

Tags: world-war-two, nuclear-weapons

It's August 6th, 1945.  The first atomic bomb ever dropped hurtles to the ground.  Its fuse fails and with a thunk it buries itself in the ground.  The Enola Gay flies home, its crew worried they did something wrong.

Now the brass back in Washington have a problem; they just hand delivered an atomic bomb to their desperate enemies, and it might be easy to repair.

I couldn't find any contingencies about it, but I'm also not a professionally trained historian with access to primary sources. I did find plans, which were abandoned, for building a giant concrete containment vessel around the Trinity device in case that failed to completely detonate, so they could save the uranium.

My question is, what, if anything was their plan for this situation?

Comment: What questions do you have that are not answered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun-type_fission_weapon "Even a "fizzle" would have completely disintegrated the device, while the multiple redundancies built into the "Little Boy" design meant there was negligible if any potential for the device to strike the ground without detonating at all."

Comment: @AllInOne: Ryan is asking what, if any, contingency plan there was if the "negligible, if any" chance turned out to be non-zero after all. I think it is a fair question (albeit about a very unlikely event).

Comment: What did your research reveal? (Please edit the answer into the question - questions should show evidence of prior research, and nobody should have to read comments to understand the question).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(nuclear_test)

Comment: Conjecture, the Fat Man would have been dropped on the same site as quickly as possible with an aim of destroying any remains before it could be moved and hidden.   The "third bomb" was several weeks delayed   link: https://www.warbirdforum.com/third.htm

Comment: Remember, Japan's surrender was already imminent at that time.

Comment: @DevSolar given the design of Little Boy, hitting the ground likely was sufficient to assemble the device, just a bit slower than desired.

Comment: It is interesting to think about:  what if the first "atomic bomb" had been specially designed to explode a day after impact with the ground - while Japan's top nuclear scientists were examining it.

Comment: The Trinity device was a plutonium bomb. It did have uranium (as a tamper), but it was not *highly enriched* uranium, so it wouldn't be the uranium that the containment vessel would be designed to save.  More likely a containment vessel would be planned to prevent the much rarer *plutonium* scattering from a misfire. The Los Alamos team was quite certain the gun-type bomb would fire; the implosion weapon was far less certain, up until the actual Trinity test.

Comment: I think that these comments are missing the point; the decision to drop the second bomb on Nagasaki was done hours before so there IS a possibility that it could have been dropped in the ocean. For instance if the pilots had run out of fuel. Then it would not in a military sense have worked leading to the OP.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If the bomb failed to explode in any way (which was unlikely, see comments and Mark's answer), the USA still would not have to worry about it (too much).

They would win the war anyway within a few months, and pick up the wrecked bomb from wherever the Japanese had stored it.

Even if Japan could figure out what that bomb was supposed to be doing and repair it, they didn't have any delivery system that could reach mainland USA (with any degree of certainty).

More importantly, the USA *knew* Japan did not have the capacities to build a second bomb, so even the microscopic chance that Japan could deliver the salvaged bomb to *some* target would not have changed the outcome.

The USA had both the delivery system and the production capacity to build a second, third, fourth bomb (of the Fat Man design), quite aside from having the strategic upper hand so firmly that they did not actually *need* the A-bomb to win the war. Not even in the very, *very* unlikely scenario of a major city, Pearl Harbor, or any other single location taken out by the salvaged Little Boy.

Comment: Well, they didn't really have enough uranium to build a second, third, fourth Little Boy.

Comment: @Vladimir F: But the US certainly had the resources to build many atomic weapons within a few years.  We know this because it did just that.

Comment: Probably the most devastating thing the Japanese could have done with a captured bomb would be to send a submarine on a suicide mission to the Okinawa, to detonate it at the staging area for Operation Olympic.  As the *Crossroads Baker* test showed, this would likely have contaminated the ships so severely that the invasion of the home islands would be put off for six months or more.  Of course, this wasn't known until after the *Crossroads Baker* test...

Comment: Perhaps, when the Japanese analyzed that bomb, to realize what it was and what little problem made it fail, in other words, the Americans have the bomb (and it was pure luck that it didn’t explode) and could easily come up with a next one that does work, they surrendered just as they did when experiencing the working bomb. After all, the message is almost the same.

Comment: Plus - in the chaos of war why would the Japanese think that dud bomb was any different than any other dud bomb, many of which already littered their landscape?

Comment: @jamesqf: Uranium enrichment until September, 1945 (thermal diffusion), produced sufficient material for a bomb every 6 months; [Plutonium enrichment process used was by August, 1945](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/what-kind-of-atomic-bombs-were-anticipated-after-nagasaki/41319#41319), produced a bomb every 7-10 days. An improved Uranium enrichment process (gaseous diffusion) that took only 3-4 weeks per bomb., providing sufficient material for a bomb nearly weekly., came online late in 1945.

Answer (score 43):

The primary contingency plan was the design of the bomb itself.  Little Boy was *not* a safe design: [any number of unplanned events could cause a detonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy#Development).  Foremost among these is impact: a 500 *g* impact, such as would happen after a 15,000-foot (4.5 km) fall, is sufficient to bring the bullet and target together, detonating the bomb.  If the bomb hit water instead of land, the water would act as a neutron moderator, causing a criticality event and severe radioactive contamination.  In the event of an airplane crash, any resulting fire will trigger the explosives, setting off the bomb.

In short, once the bomb is fully assembled, it's very hard to *keep* it from going off.  In the event that the crew of *Enola Gay* had to abort their mission, they had no intention of trying to land with the bomb still aboard.

Comment: Michael MacAskill, the 500g impact would be the sudden stop upon hitting the ground.  I have no idea what the actual acceleration would be, but that's what he's talking about.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill, when the bomb hits the ground, it'll come to an abrupt stop.  Given the design of the bomb and the sort of surface it's most likely to hit, that stop will involve a force more than 500 times that of gravity if the bomb was dropped from 15,000 feet or more above the ground.

Comment: @Michael MacAskill: (Sigh) It would have accelerated to terminal velocity as it fell. When it hit the ground, it would have decelerated rather quickly.  Think bug on a windshield :-)

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill just because the accelerations involved in a collision are very time-sensitive doesn't mean they aren't meaningful. If the detonation mechanism depends on a force between two internal components exceeding a certain magnitude then the local acceleration *must* pass the threshold to develop this force inertially. Accelerating at 90% of the rate for 10 times the duration would dissipate much more energy, but not in a way that would disturb the mechanism.

Comment: Don't count on the force of impact to trigger the bomb. Even a crude gun-type atomic bomb requires a carefully controlled explosion. Crashing against the ground would damage the bomb in ways that would prevent an explosion. Even a fizzle.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill There's no discontinuity. The object deforms as it hits the ground.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Discontinuities do not exist in nature except in very limited circumstances, and this isn't one of them. The acceleration spikes sharply upon impact, but that doesn't make it discontinuous or non-differentiable.

Comment: @mark, I just posted a follow up question to this one that you might have the answer to... https://history.stackexchange.com/q/52532/37759

Comment: @Rekesoft Agreed. The 500g impact isn't "any 500g impact," it's a criterion along with others such that the material becomes critical. There are multiple scenarios from full detonation, through detonation but only dispersal, through nothing at all and just a crater with mangled parts.

Comment: You have grossly misrepresented the science and engineering of the *Little Boy* bomb. For example: "*.. tests showed that [detonation in case of a plane crash] would require a highly unlikely impact of 500 times the force of gravity.*"

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Plane crash is quite a different event, though; while planes crash hard enough to kill people, it's nowhere near the deceleration of an atomic bomb (a rather dense object with few deformation zones) hitting the ground from a high altitude drop. I'm not saying the bomb would detonate properly, but the two scenarios aren't comparable at all.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the above mentioned facts that the bomb would go off very easily and would be useless even after a fizzle, and that Japan was in no position to get a nuclear weapons programme off the ground, the U.S. didn't really need a contingency plan.

Japan had already started overtures for a general surrender before the bomb was dropped. The excuse the U.S. used for dropping the bomb was that they didn't like one of the conditions of the surrender, namely that the emperor would remain Japan's head of state. If the bomb hadn't gone off, the U.S. would have simply accepted Japan's surrender with the condition and leave the emperor on the throne, which the U.S. ended up doing anyway.

Comment: Your timeline seems to be a bit off.  The overtures prior to the bombings were attempts to get the Soviet Union (then a nominally neutral party) to mediate, trying to get a *status quo ante bellum* surrender: returning to the situation prior to the start of the Second Sino-Japanese War.  The "surrender with one condition" offer was transmitted on August 10, one day *after* Nagasaki was bombed.